# Notarizing .dmg with altool not returning result

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-catalina, notarize

I am trying to notarise an existing plugin installer in a dmg container.
Apple's advise is to use the altool to notarise via terminal.
I am using the following code:

```sh
xcrun altool --notarize-app \
  --primary-bundle-id co.nz.xxx.dmg \
  --username xxxx@gmail.com \
  --password xxxxxxxxxxx \
  --file /Users/admin/Documents/MyPlugin_v1.7.dmg
```

But this is not returning any result, no error, no success. I waited long enough too.

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

It takes a baker’s dozen or so minutes to notarize.  There is no more result to expect other than the uuid returned to you after the upload.  Once Apple notarizes your app, the status attached to the given uuid will change. You can check that it went thru by polling the status, then staple.

For detailed information:
See the man page for altool
and 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow

Comment: Thanks. But I don't get the uuid returned either. It's just crickets after I hit return.

Comment: For how long does it cricket?

Comment: Upload speed too slow?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I changed the syntax and it worked.

```
xcrun altool --notarize-app -f /Users/admin/Documents/myplugin_v1.7.dmg --primary-bundle-id co.nz.xxxx.dmg -u xxxx@gmail.com -p xxxxxx
```